# IValueConverter does not fire when XamGrid is deserialized

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, infragistics

While I have worked with C# for a number of years now, I must admit that I am new to WPF + Infragistics controls.  If you have any insight, I would love to hear your thoughts on the following scenario:

1. The PersistenceManager is configured for the XamGrid using XAML. (see: [B] Persist Everything)
2. application starts (for the first time)
3. XamGrid is bound to a datasource
4. binding includes a converter (see: [A] Column Binding )
5. **the converter works as expected**
6. user adjusts the size of the `Id` column
7. data is serialized via: `PersistenceManager.Save(IgPersistenceGroup);`
8. application closed
9. application started (for the second time)
10. `XamGrid` is derserialized via: `PersistenceManager.Load(IgPersistenceGroup, _persistedData.IgPersistenceMemoryStream);`
11. `XamGrid` is bound to the data source
12. new data is displayed as expected
13. **the converter's constructor is never called**, as a result, the wrong data is displayed
14. the `Id` column is the expected size

In this particular case, the `XamGrid`'s entire object tree is being serialized/deserialized.  As a result, I suspect that my problem is related to:

1. the bindings being serialized/deserialized, or
2. the converter is being referenced as a `StaticResource` and that that reference no longer makes sense when the application starts for a second time

So my question is: why doesn't the `IValueConverter` load when the `XamGrid` is deserialized?

Practically speaking, there is no need to serialize the entire `XamGrid`... but that is an entirely separate issue.

**ADDITIONAL CONTEXT**

- Infragistics controls version 12.1.20121.2286

**SAMPLE CODE**

**[A] Column Binding**

```
<ig:TemplateColumn  Key="Severity" HeaderText="Event Severity">
<ig:TemplateColumn.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate x:Name="SeverityColumn">
      <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource SourceToTargetConverter}}" />
   </DataTemplate>
</ig:TemplateColumn.ItemTemplate>
</ig:TemplateColumn>
```

** SourceToTargetConverter: is not the converter's real name - the converter's name is irrelevant here

**[B] Persist Everything**

```
<ig:XamGrid ig:PersistenceManager.PersistenceGroup="{DynamicResource igPG}" 

<ig:PersistenceManager.Settings>
   <ig:PersistenceSettings SavePersistenceOptions="AllButIgnored" >
      <ig:PersistenceSettings.PropertySettings>
         <ig:PropertyNamePersistenceInfo PropertyName="FilteringSettings"/>
      </ig:PersistenceSettings.PropertySettings>
   </ig:PersistenceSettings>
</ig:PersistenceManager.Settings>
```

**REFERENCES**

- [Using Infragistics Control Persistence Framework](http://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/Persistence_Using_IG_Control_Persistence_Framework.html)
- [About Infragistics Control Persistence Framework](http://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/Persistence_About_IG_Control_Persistence_Framework.html)
- [MSDN: IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the `TemplateColumn.ItemTemplate` (aka: SeverityColumn) is not being serialized when the `XamGrid` is persisted using the `ig:PersistenceManager`.  As a result:

1. When the application starts for the first time, the `TemplateColumn.ItemTemplate` is loaded from BAML and the column is displayed with the appropriate formatting (using the supplied `IValueConverter`).

   - NOTE: you will be able to see the `ItemTemplate` using *Visual Studio's* debugger and the *Watch* window
2. In the current configuration, the `ig:PersistenceManager` is explicitly setting the `TemplateColumn.ItemTemplate` to null when the `XamGrid` is being deserialized.

   - the reason why unformatted data is being displayed in the column is because the XamGrid is automatically falling back to the `ig:TemplateColumn`'s `Key` to load data from the `DataContext`

**UPDATE 1**

Now that I have a better understanding of the *what*, I can provide an explanation for the *why*.  The following is taken directly from the Infragistics documentation:

*"There are some types of properties that are not saved by the Infragistics Control Persistence Framework. It does not save AttachedProperties, **DataTemplates**, Paths, ControlTemplates, Styles, and ItemPanelTemplates."*

[SOURCE: [About Infragistics Control Persistence Framework](http://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/Persistence_About_IG_Control_Persistence_Framework.html)]